# Why does the method "getChildren" doesn't work with Pane?

Tags: javafx-8

I have searched for the answer but only found the same Problem with the GridPane and the solution ( to use the method "getContent()" or "getTabs()") doesn't work for me, because it's also no possible method for Pane.

What I want to do is to add a Button to the Pane-Element. I searched for solutions and they use always the getchildren().add(Node e) methods.

Here is my Code, i checked if the class of my object is Pane and yes the System.out shows that it is Pane.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Lost.fxml"));

    Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
    Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
    stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
    stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
    stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
    stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

    Button startButton = new Button("Start1");
    //Einfügen des Eventhandlers des Buttons
    startButton.setOnAction(null);
    //Bestimmen der Position des Buttons
    startButton.setPrefHeight((stage.getHeight()/2));
    startButton.setPrefWidth((stage.getWidth()/2));

    System.out.println(root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0).getClass());
```

> root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0).getChildren();

```
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}
```

I'm really thankful for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the top layout in "Lost.fxml" is an AnchorPane you can directly specify it while loading it:

```
AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.<AnchorPane>load(getClass().getResource("Lost.fxml"));
```

Your actual problem:

> Why does the method “getChildren” doesn't work with Pane?

Because in the line

```
root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0).getChildren();
```

`.getChildrenUnmodifiable()` will return `ObservableList<Node>` and
`.get(0)` will return a `Node` at index 0 of this list and, the Node is a top base class for all nodes (panes, controls etc.), which does not have a 
`.getChildren()` method.

If you are sure that at the index=0 of children list, there is a `Pane`, you can cast to it:

```
 ObservableList<Node> paneChildren = ( (Pane) root.getChildren().get(0) ).getChildren();
 paneChildren.add( new Button("Do it!") );
```

I used root.getChildren() rather than root.getChildrenUnmodifiable(), since we have `AnchorPane root` at the top now.

Comment: I meant the getChildren() method after get(0).

I cant use the getChildren() method on my root because it says "it has protected acess in Parent"

And I want to add the Button not to the variable root (which is my AnchorPane), but to my Pane.

So i cant use it on Pane, cause i get the object Pane with the method getChildrenUmodifiable?

Than how can I use getChildren on my Parent object?

PS: Thank you for helping me, hope you can understand my "further problem" :)